# How to install debootstrap script jammy Ubuntu 22.04 LTS for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: debootstrap

How to install debootstrap script jammy Ubuntu 22.04 LTS for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

The newest version of the debootstrap package for Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS:

```
apt-cache policy debootstrap: 1.0.95ubuntu0.9 bionic-updates/main
ls /usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/
```

There is no script for jammy.

Solution option:

```
cd /usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/
sudo mv gutsy /home/$user/gutsy_old
sudo wget https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/debootstrap/-/raw/master/scripts/gutsy
sudo ln -sfn gutsy jammy
ls -l jammy : lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 17:50 jammy -> gutsy
```

I haven't used this option yet:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/debootstrap/debootstrap_1.0.126+nmu1_all.deb
sudo apt install ./debootstrap_1.0.126+nmu1_all.deb
```

I am currently working on 18.04.6 LTS. I need a minimal 22.04 image for testing(minbase). In Ubuntu 18.04.6, the old debootstrap package. I got out of the situation by the described method. I am interested in whether the debootstrap package will be updated in the 18.04.6 LTS repository or should I continue using my method?

Comment: Jammy → debootstrap https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/debootstrap

Comment: A small mistake in the question. It should be like this: sudo mv gutsy /home/$USER/gutsy_old I will not edit. Disadvantages are added.

Answer (score 1):

Found the debootstrap package with jammy here(Change log for debootstrap package in Ubuntu - [1.0.95ubuntu0.10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debootstrap/+changelog#:%7E:text=1.0.95ubuntu0.10))

[image]

Setting Pin-Priority:

```
sudo cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/bionic-proposed.pref
Package: *
Pin: release a=bionic-proposed
Pin-Priority: -1
EOF
```

Adding a bionic-proposed repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic-proposed restricted main multiverse universe'
sudo apt -t bionic-proposed install debootstrap
apt-cache policy debootstrap
```

[image]

The stable version of Ubuntu 22.04 is scheduled to be released on April 21, 2022. The development is already going in full swing and it will follow this release schedule:

```
February 24, 2022: Feature freeze
March 17, 2022: UI freeze
March 31, 2022: Beta release
April 14, 2022: Release candidate
April 21, 2022: Final stable release
```

Comment: A small correction in the answer. I was in a hurry. It is better in this order: /ubuntu bionic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse After add-apt-repository, it is desirable to do this: sudo apt-get clean && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && sudo apt update and then: sudo apt -t bionic-proposed install debootstrap